# Permissions of /etc changed

Tags: 12.04

I changed the permissions of the folder `/etc`. Owner-from `root` to (my username).All access to read and write.

Group-from root to (my username).

I did this to get manual login in my pc by adding `greeter-show-manual-login true`.

It worked and now I do have the manual login at startup but every time I write a command in terminal starting with `sudo`,it says

```
/etc/sudoers mode is 0640, should be 0440.
Error no valid sudoers found
```

and it exits.

I reversed the permissions I made to the `/etc` folder,but it is still showing the same thing in terminal.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't properly `sudo` at the moment, you can try using `pkexec` :

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```